# Check functions for equality inside a macro

Tags: macros, clojure

I have a macro where I need to check whether first element of the passed form is exactly the clojure.core/not function. How could I achieve that?

```
(defmacro foo [form]
  (println (= clojure.core/not (first form)))) ; expect true here, but its false
```

And I use that macro like so:

```
(foo (not smthng))
```

I've heard about resolving symbols with #' but how could it help me in this case (if it even could be helpful)? 
Any thoughts are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the macro above there is no syntax quoting/namespacing of symbols going on, so the first thing in the form would just be 'not.

```
(defmacro foo [form]
  (println (first form)))

(foo (not nil))
;=> not
```

So a simple macro to check for the first symbol being `not` would be:

```
(defmacro foo [form]
   (println (= 'not (first form))))
```

**EDIT**

To ensure that you have the correct `clojure.core/not` (and not some other not that might have been referred), you can use the `resolve` function to get a fully qualified var.

```
(defmacro foo [form]
  (if (= #'clojure.core/not (resolve (first form)))
    (println "(first form) is clojure.core/not")
    (println "(first form) is not clojure.core/not")))

 (foo (not nil))
 ;;=> "(first form) is clojure.core/not"

 (foo (+ 3 4))
 ;;=> "(first form) is not clojure.core/not"
```

Comment: I didn't know how to write `#'~(first form)`. Its a little bit confusing syntax. But it works as expected, thanks a lot

Comment: Final code that works for me is `(if (= #'clojure.core/not (eval \`#'~(first form))) \`(macro-returns-this-code-if-true) \`(this-if-false))`. Could you complement your answer? Suppose it would be helpful for other users.

Comment: @hsestupin - good work! I've also edited my answer a little bit - your comment prompted me to do some more investigation (mainly to see if there was a way around using `eval`). I found the `resolve` function - which looks like a cleaner fit for what you want than my previous suggestion. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for investigation! `resolve` is great. Also now I'm using it too in my code.